# Request header field is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers with $http

Tags: angularjs, post, http-headers, request, http-post

I'm doing a *POST* to a service using **Postman Chrome Extension**, and I get the expected response.

But, when I do the same *POST* request using `$http`, all goes to hell.

I get a :

```
Request header field Engaged-Auth-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

`Engaged-Auth-Token` being a header.

I've no idea why with Postman works and it doesn't work with Chrome...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` from request Header. To fix this we need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` to request header

Add a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to the `http request header`. You can do this at app level using `$httpProvider`. Add below line in your app config section to add this header.

```
var app = angular.module("app", [
    "ngRoute",
    "app.controllers",
    "app.directives",
    "app.filters"
]);

app.config([
    "$routeProvider",
    "$httpProvider",
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
    }
]);
```

Comment: I believe this needs to read $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'; Note the quotes around * otherwise you'll get all kinds of errors.

Answer (score 7):

I believe configuring the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** on the $httpProvider on the CLIENT will not work. I think the header needs to be configured on the server (as a response header). In a node-express application for instance, this could be done with a middleware (for example), putting something like this:

```
res.header('*')
```

or (more selectively) just the headers you need:

```
res.header('Engaged-Auth-Token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
```

Answer (score 0):

if use sails api on backend change cors.js and add your token filed here

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
  headers: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Engaged-Auth-Token'
};
```